# Finding the start and end of a sequence in a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a long data frame that I want to find the end and beggining of a sequence.  To simplify

```
b = c("a","c","a","c","e", "a","c","a","c","a" ,"c","a","c","a","c" ,"d","d","d","d","d")
a = c(0,0,0,0,1, 4,0,0,0,0, 5,1,6,0,0, 0,10,0,0,0)
df = data.frame(a,b)
```

What I'd like is a way to find all the Non-Zero to 0 and 0 to Non-Zero transitions.

I've done this by using `lapply` to call a function and saving the value from the previous call.

I'm looking something more elegant that would let me look at Row N and Row N+1, or better yet Row N to Row N+M in my function or something better yet.

Comment: You can find them via `rle(Data$a==0)` but there may be a more useful way to group the sequences, depending on your end goal.

Comment: To elaborate on Joshua's comment:  `Data$a==0` returns logical 1 for zeroes and logical 0 for everything else, thus making `rle`'s output exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you want? It might not be elegant, but it should detect transitions you describe.

```
> lagn <- function(x, n) { c(rep(NA,n), x[1:(length(x)-n)]) }
> df$c <- lagn(df$a, 1)
# mult ensures one of the item is zero, add ensures one of the item was nonzero
> df[which( (df$a*df$c)==0 & (df$a+df$c)!=0),]
    a b  c
5   1 e  0
7   0 c  4
11  5 c  0
14  0 a  6
17 10 d  0
18  0 d 10
```